# Is there a way to remove duplicate emails from a remote account?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, apple-mail, deduplication

I have a  user who has multiple duplicated emails across multiple folders on his IMAP account. How he managed to create them is beyond me, but mine is not to reason why, just to fix it!

Can anyone recommend an application that I may use to remove the duplicates. (we're talking mailboxes in excess of 9G, and it's a remote server)

I don't mind what OS I have to use to clean up the mailbox, I'm just looking for some recommendations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully used the [Remove Duplicates](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/remove-duplicate-messages/) Thunderbird extension in the past for this task.

[image]

Comment: I like this option, I will look into this immediately!! Thanks a lot